# mqsql - check if selected rows contain the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check in mysql if certain columns contain the same value, but don't actually know the value yet. All the solutions I found until now were using count in combination with a where clause. But that doesn't work for me, because I don't know the values of the colums. For example:

```
Index   ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
1       1       cat     1.3     black
2       1       cat     1.3     black
3       1       cat     1.3     white
4       1       cat     1.3     tiger
5       1       cat     1.3     white
```

I would like to check if the 3 columns ColB,ColC and ColD have the same value. For the table above it should return true. However for the following table it should return false

```
Index   ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
1       1       dog     1.3     black
2       1       cat     1.3     black
3       2       cat     1.3     white
4       1       cat     1.3     tiger
5       1       cat     2.7     white
```

The rule should be sth like that: if(ColB_hasDifferentValues || ColC_hasDifferentValues || ColD_hasDifferentValues) { return true } ;

Is that possible? As I said before, I don't know which animals are included in ColC, as users can insert new animals.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar at all with java and jdbc?

Comment: If i understand your question, you want to check that all the rows for a table have ColB ColC and ColD equals right? If only one rows is different then you want to have false?

Comment: @EthanMoore no I haven't used jbdc yet. As I wrote in the answer, I am using mysql.

Comment: @olibiaz: yes exactly. But I think Gordon's answer already solved it.

Comment: @S.F. I know you are, but I'm using Java with mySQL, too. So I was just curious. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `max()` and `min()`:

```
select (case when max(b) = min(b) and max(c) = min(c) and max(d) = min(d)
             then 'same'
             else 'different'
        end)
from t;
```

This logic ignores `NULL` values (the OP does not mention `NULL` values at all).  The idea can be extended, but the logic is a wee bit more complex.